# Populate a Field with the Error from Try and Catch statement in Suitescript 2.1

Tags: suitescript

how do I populate a field M/R field (custitem_mr_field) from the error that was thrown in the try and catch statement? Do I have to use submitFields or setValue?

try{

//Insert code here

```
    } catch (e) {
        log.error(JSON.stringify(e));
        throw e.message;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue I have seen with this is that when I try to access the "e" inside the catch, it has always been undefined for some reason (at lease inside of a suitelet) so I would always end up with an exception that e is undefined instead of being able to strigify or access e.message.     I don't know if anyone else has seen that issue or not.

Comment: That's weird, you should be able to see the error but you can try sending it back as a context.response.write OR throwing the error

Answer (score 0):

You can use both, it depends on the situation. If the record that you want to update the error on is already loaded (you loaded it for some other reason OR you are in a User Event / Client Script in EDIT) so you should use setValue otherwise use submitFields.